# load a form more than once using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I simply want to load a form/div more than once using a loop. Tried this -

```
for (i=1; i<=4; i++) {
            //document.write(i);
            showObj('poidiv','block');
        }
// here poidiv is the name of a html div defined earlier

function showObj(objname,visibility){
        document.getElementById(objname).style.display= visibility;
    }
```

but not working.

Is it actually possible to load the same div/form more than once using javascript?

Comment: I don't see much AJAX related code in your snippet. Are you sure you are not mixing some notions here?

Comment: I just need to load an html div more than once using loop. I'm new at this javascript platform. So, any sort of example will be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "load"? When you say AJAX it sounds like the form html is downloaded separate to the main page (i.e. in another file), but from your example it looks like you just want to "duplicate" a form that's already on the page.

Comment: I created a div and kept it hidden. So want to load it several times under a loop. The number of iteration will be dynamic. That's what I wanna do so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use some other method for accessing your element as you can only reference single elements by ID. an option would be to reference them by class, or were it my choice, use jQuery and it's built in selector..

```
var myHTML='...whatever';  // this is the HTML we built somewhere
var myDIV=$('<div/>');     // here we create a DOM object in jQuery
$(myDiv).addClass('myClass'); // here we add a class so we can find them later
$(myDiv).append(myHTML);  // here we insert the HTML we built earlier and referenced up top

for(x=1;x<=4,x++){  // here we loop
   $('#someDistinceElementOnPage').append($(myDiv));  // here we append that HTML with it's surrounding DIV to some element on the page
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't have that much idea about jQuery. Can anyone provide any example with javascript?

Comment: Download: code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js. Read: docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery. 
Try it, it'll seriously make your life easier, despite being another thing to learn.